# Google Play Billing (Create Subscription button not clickable)

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I am trying to implement the google pay billing into my application, I want to implement the auto monthly subscription when I go to "In app product" section under it, I selected the "subscription" option then I want to create new subscription but the button (create subscription) not clickable.
[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add the billing dependency in your app gradle and upload once is Play Store. Create Subscription button will be enabled after that. During development of the app, you can Publish the app to Alpha Release (Closed testing)